# Qt Creator cannot resolve STL containers

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, stdvector

I've downloaded Qt 5.4 for Windows, running it in Windows 8.1 Pro. It comes with MingW and Qt Creator 3.3.

I've been using Qt for few years. Still a very necessary component seems missing in the Qt Creator IDE. Suppose a class `Card` is defined with a function `getSymbol()`:

```
class Card
{
public:
    string getSymbol() const;
}
```

Somewhere in code I've a `std::vector` of `Card`s:

```
vector<Card> playable;
```

And somewhere else in code:

```
playable[0].getSymbol();
           ^----------------- Note this dot
```

When I type the period in the line above, Qt Creator should list available functions and variables of `Card` class to be used, just like IntelliSense works in VS. But that doesn't happen. However, when I create an object of type `Card`, then the dot triggers Qt Creator to show available functions:

[image]

Why this feature doesn't work when `Card` objects are put in STL containers? Is there any settings that needs to be enabled?

Comment: I have the same issue but I believe it is a limitation of QtCreator and the right place for this would be a bug report/feature request.

Comment: There is [this bug report](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTCREATORBUG-8922).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been a long standing issue discussed asked and asked over again on forums and mailing lists. As thuga correctly showed in the comment, this is the corresponding bugreport to monitor:

[Code completion does not work for std::vector of objects](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTCREATORBUG-8922)

Note that QtCreator was primarily meant for working with Qt code and so you would use `QVector` in such projects which is working. I am not saying that it is not worth fixing, but that is at least the history.

This may be getting closer and closer with using clang inside QtCreator, but I guess you will need to wait.